# Paging wise sorting is not working using tablesorter and tablepaging jquery plugins

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, sorting, tablesorter

This is my js code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () 
    {


        $("table.tablesorter").tablesorter({ widthFixed: true, sortList: [[0, 0]], widgets: ['zebra'], sortLocaleCompare: true })


       $("table.tablesorter").tablesorterPager({ container: $("#pager"), size: $(".pagesize option:selected").val() });
    });

 </script>
```

This is my Paging code in html:

```
<div id="pager" style="position:relative;margin-top:3px;">

        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/first.png")" class="first" />
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/prev.png")" class="prev" />
        <input type="text" class="pagedisplay" style ="font-family:Arial;font-size:10px;" />
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/next.png")" class="next" />
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/last.png")" class="last" />
        <select class="pagesize">
            <option selected="selected" value="10">10</option>

            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
            <option value="40">40</option>
        </select>

    </div>
```

Sorting is working fine,but my problem is:
If I am in second page (Paging) of table and click the table headers columns for sorting then it sort the entire table. So the row values in my 2nd page gets changed. Is there any way to sort only the values in the current page of the table.

Can anyone please help me out how to do resolve this.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want to do this, but I'm guessing that ajax is not being used. The important question to ask here is how would you distinguish between sorting the visible page and the entire table when clicking on the header?

Comment: Hi,I am not using ajax. Actually per page i am having 10 records i just want to sort those 10 records instead of sorting all the table values. Hope you got my point i guess.